# NodeJS code understanding

Tags: node.js, express

I am fairly new to nodejs and have been looking at some code and trying to make sense of it. Can someone please bear with me and help me understand the following code fragments. My questions may be very basic but please understand that I am learning nodejs and express and have been trying hard to understand some existing code. I have marked the code lines with numbers and the questions are posed by the same number.

```
var ChatApp = global.ChatApp = {}
, conf = ChatApp.conf = require('./conf').config (1)
, http = require('http') (2)
, path = require('path') (3)
, express = require('express')
, app = express()
;

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views'); 
app.set('view engine', 'jade'); 
app.use(express.logger('dev')); (6)
app.use(express.bodyParser()); (7)

app.use(express.methodOverride()); (8)
app.use(express.cookieParser('your secret here')); (9)
app.use(express.session({secret: 'PTKACSxSq24PlZ9IAPRMy3_2'})); (10)

app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
var oneof = false;
    if(req.headers.origin) {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
        oneof = true;
    }
    if(req.headers['access-control-request-method']) {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', req.headers['access-control-request-method']);
        oneof = true;
    }
    if(req.headers['access-control-request-headers']) {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', req.headers['access-control-request-headers']);
        oneof = true;
    }
    if(oneof) {
        res.header('Access-Control-Max-Age', 60 * 60 * 24 * 365);
    } (11)

    // intercept OPTIONS method
    if (oneof && req.method == 'OPTIONS') {
        res.send(200);
    }
    else {
        next();
    }
}); (12)

app.use(app.router); (13)
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
} (15)

server = http.createServer(app); (16)

require('./lib/chat').init(server); (17)
```

(1) I understand what require does but `conf = ChatApp.conf = require('./conf').config` ? Are we making a variable conf and making it equal to ChatApp. conf? Also is the require is pointing to `parent directory/conf/config` ? I ask this because in my parent directory where this file exists , there is no conf folder. There is just a conf. js file but it gets included in this variable (checked with console.log). How does it happen?

(2),(3) `require(http)` and require(path). Why is the need to include http and path? What purpose do these 2 solve?

(6)app.use(express.logger('dev')) From express website, it is used to log every request. My question is what is the parameter dev in the function for? Is it a path ?

(7) `app.use(express.bodyParser())` : From express website: Request body parsing middleware supporting JSON, urlencoded, and multipart requests. This middleware is simply a wrapper the json(), urlencoded(), and multipart() middleware.  But what does it really mean? What does express.bodyparser do?

(8) `app.use(express.methodOverride());` No explanation on express website. Not sure what it means and why is it used.

(9) `express.cookieparser` parses the cookie header field. but what is a header field in a cookie. From what I know, a browser cookie has the following fields. Name, Content, Domain, Path, Send For, Expires.

(10) `app.use(express.session({secret: 'PTKACSxSq24PlZ9IAPRMy3_2'}));` I couldn't find any method called express.session(). What does it do?

(12) For code fragmant 12, I couldn't understand what are we trying to achieve with it?

(13) app.use(app.router) When I did a console.log of app.router, it gave me this

```
function router(req, res, next){
    self._dispatch(req, res, next);
  }
```

Any idea why are we doing this? It appears to be a generic router function but why is the need to include it?

(15) `app.get.env` gave me development and it is coming from a file within `express/lib/application.js`. Why are we doing this test? 
(16) This is totally confusing. I have seen this 
`var server = http.createServer() and var app = express()` which means express has a built in http server within it but why would be do `http.createserver(express())` or `http.createserver(app)`?

(17) There is a lib/chat folder in my app root but it has a host of files with an index.js file in it. Does it mean to include the index.js file in that or all the js files in the folder? And why the init server?

Any help from anyone would be greatly apreciated.

Comment: Wow. It's [_one question many answers_](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts). If you have so many questions, it might be better to actually talk to someone about that code fragment.

Comment: I actually am not able to catch hold of anyone in person. Would you be able to spare some time to help me with this.

Comment: Since you found the code somewhere, it might be a good idea to ask the original author your questions.

Comment: The code was written by a developer I had hired. He has since then disappeared so now I am banging my head on the code to understand it :)

Comment: This question will undoubtedly be closed shortly. Consider revising to focus on one issue per question, or getting a tutor to explain a whole module to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Disclaimer

The following answers won't tell you what the following things are: HTTP request, REST, sessions. Also note that it's rather unlikely that you will ever get so many questions answered again.

## Answers

> (1) I understand what require does but `conf = ChatApp.conf = require('./conf').config`? Are we making a variable `conf` and making it equal to `ChatApp.conf`?

Yes

> Also is the require is pointing to parent directory/conf/config?

No. It's requiring either `./conf.js` or `./conf.node`, `.js` is preferred. The module exports a `config` field, which gets accessed.

> (2),(3) require(http) and require(path). Why is the need to include http and path? What purpose do these 2 solve?

[`http`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html) is necessary for the HTTP server, [`path`](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html) for path-based functions.

> (6)app.use(express.logger('dev')) From express website, it is used to log every request. My question is what is the parameter dev in the function for? Is it a path ?

It's the [logger middleware from Connect](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/middleware/logger.js):

> - `dev` concise output colored by response status for development use
>
> (7) app.use(express.bodyParser()) : From express website: Request body parsing middleware supporting JSON, urlencoded, and multipart requests. This middleware is simply a wrapper the json(), urlencoded(), and multipart() middleware. But what does it really mean? What does express.bodyparser do?

It enables you to parse the body of HTTP requests. If you don't know what a HTTP request is, you might stop to read the rest of the answer, learn a little bit about HTTP, and get back for the rest.

> (8) app.use(express.methodOverride()); No explanation on express website. Not sure what it means and why is it used.

Most web browsers only support the HTTP verbs GET and POST. However, in order to provide a RESTful service (another fancy word), one also needs PUT/PATCH and DELETE. `methodOveride` enables you to create forms which will be sent by POST, but interpreted according to their `_method` attribute.

> (9) express.cookieparser parses the cookie header field. but what is a header field in a cookie. From what I know, a browser cookie has the following fields. Name, Content, Domain, Path, Send For, Expires.

Well, remember about HTTP request? A cookie gets send in the header of your browser's HTTP request. That's the `Cookie:` header.

> (10) app.use(express.session({secret: 'PTKACSxSq24PlZ9IAPRMy3_2'})); I couldn't find any method called express.session(). What does it do?

It enables you to use sessions.

> (12) For code fragmant 12, I couldn't understand what are we trying to achieve with it?

This fragment addresses access control for [cross-site requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

> (13) app.use(app.router) When I did a console.log of app.router, it gave me this
>
> ```
> function router(req, res, next){
>     self._dispatch(req, res, next);
>   }
> ```
>
> Any idea why are we doing this? It appears to be a generic router function but why is the need to include it?

`app.router` will route the requests. For example `app.get('/hello-world')´ will take all requests with`GET /hello-world`. You need to use`app.router` in order to enable this behaviour.

> (15) app.get.env gave me development and it is coming from a file within express/lib/application.js. Why are we doing this test?

Because we want to handle errors with a nice error message.

> (16) This is totally confusing. I have seen this var server = http.createServer() and var app = express() which means express has a built in http server within it but why would be do http.createserver(express()) or http.createserver(app)?

Because that's the express 3.x way of doing it, it doesn't come with a fully-fledged http server anymore. This way, you can use your `app` as callback for many other things.

> (17) There is a lib/chat folder in my app root but it has a host of files with an index.js file in it. Does it mean to include the index.js file in that or all the js files in the folder? And why the init server?

It includes the `index.js`. `init(server)` will probably do some things to the server. You need to check the according file.